# shutdown, but still allow new logins

Tags: shutdown

I have a Linux VM on [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) in [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) that starts up, performs a task, and then shuts itself down.  I am issuing the shutdown command like this:

```
shutdown -h 5
```

I have a 5 minute delay to give myself time to `ssh` into the server and cancel the shutdown if I want to do something with the server.

The problem I have is once I issue the shutdown command, Linux will no longer allow new logins.  There doesn't seem to be anything in the man page to allow it to issue a shutdown, but still allow new logins.

Is there a way to issue this shutdown command, but still allow a new `ssh` login?

Comment: The purpose of the delay is to allow an existing process to complete, not to give you a chance to start something new. Don't use `shutdown` unless you are prepared to stop using the machine immediately until after restart.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could simply not use `shutdown` with a time specification, but

```
echo shutdown -h now | at now + 5 minutes
```

or similar; a simple

```
sleep $((60*5)) ; shutdown -h now
```

would do, too.

However, using `at` has the advantage that you can review waiting commands using `atq` and cancel them using `atrm`.

Comment: This at command is perfect, thank you. I was already using a sleep, but it's harder to cancel the shutdown since I have to kill the shell script in order to prevent the shutdown.

Comment: Note that this approach will **not inform** the users.

Comment: @Jeff, if you have `sleep; shutdown` and kill the script during the sleep, I think it should stop and not do the shutdown. You could also use `sleep && shutdown`, so even if kill just the _sleep_ command, the script would skip running the shutdown.

Comment: The downside of `at` is that if you ever shutdown manually before the 5 minutes, then at startup, `at` will run the tasks that should have been run during the shutdown time and will then shut down immediately again.

Comment: @VincentFourmond oh I didn't even know that. But my guess is that in case of an EC2 VM, it probably won't matter, as its lifetime probably ends there (but that's making assumptions on the way OP is using AWS)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the suggestion. '&&' is a nice improvement to the sleep technique so I wouldn't have to kill the entire script, just the sleep.

Comment: Note that GNU `sleep` which the OP will have since it's a Linux VM, can take minutes, hours and even days as arguments so you could just do `sleep 5m && shutdown -h`.

Comment: @terdon yep, GNU sleep can do that, but I don't think busybox' sleep does, and this might be an Alpine or similar VM, which would be rather typical for a cloud VM.

Comment: @terdon update: I tried, current busybox can!

Comment: Yes, and your approach is 100% portable (as far as I know, anyway). My comment wasn't intended as criticism, just thought it might be useful for someone else. Update: huh! Busubox is improving!

Comment: @terdon I know, didn't take it negatively :) The feedback is always appreciated!!

Comment: @jiwopene Do a `shutdown -k 5 && shutdown -c " " && echo shutdown -h now | at now + 5 minutes`?  This causes a shutdown message and nologin, then stops it, then schedules a real shutdown in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

Usually, `shutdown` creates the file `/etc/nologin`, which the `login` command understands to deny non-root logins.

This leaves you two obvious options:

1. Connect as `root` (prefer to use public-key authentication rather than a password for this).
2. Remove the `/etc/nologin` file after starting the shutdown.  Be aware that new users connecting won't have seen the `wall` message warning of the impending shutdown; that could be deleterious to their sessions.

Comment: +1 for "deleterious to their sessions"

Comment: Sadly I don't see my vm creating this file when issuing the shutdown command with a time.  The man page for nologin also mentions /var/run/nologin, but I don't see that either.

Comment: @Jeff The man page for `shutdown` on my Ubuntu with systemd says _"If the time argument is used, 5 minutes before the system goes down the /run/nologin file is created to ensure that further logins shall not be allowed."_. So, if you start it with a 5 min delay, you probably could delete the file just after. But with a longer delay, you'd have to wait for the file to appear to be able to remove it...

Comment: Did you mean `/run/nologin` instead of `/etc/nologin`? It seems odd for a file like that to be created on `/etc` and not `/run` or maybe `/proc` or any other such filesystem.

Comment: I was just quoting from the `login` man page.  It does seem reasonable on modern systems for `/etc/nologin` to be a symlink to something on `/run` (though not `/proc`, which is usually a `procfs` filesystem).

Comment: @terdon, I seem to recall `/etc/nologin` being used in pre-systemd systems, but haven't used any variant of `nologin` for a long time. The [Debian manpage `nologin(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages/nologin.5.en.html) still says `/etc/nologin` too.

Comment: Ah, yes: systemd may well move things around - not sure whether the OP's platform has that.

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution is to not actually run `shutdown` too soon. Instead, sleep for some time first and run `shutdown` only when the delay is over.

If the job runs as a shell script, this is easy. You'll also need some way to stop the shutdown from eventually happening. You could either just kill the script, or have the script e.g. check some file after the sleep is over to stop the shutdown:

```
sleep 300
if ! [ -e /noshutdown ]; then
    shutdown -h now
fi
```

Comment: The downside to delayed `shutdown now` is that users get very little time to act on the warning message that's written to all terminals.  It might be worth adding a suitable `wall` command to the script.

Comment: @TobySpeight, sure, though in this case, there probably weren't online users to begin with.